# Why Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Aggregation is not caching layered navigation filters?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, layered-navigation, performance

A question for an expert. Make sure you read the preamble - the question is at the bottom.

In `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php` I noticed a functionality to cache `_getItemsData` output:

```
122         $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey().'_'.$this->_requestVar;
123         $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);
```

but it turns out `$this->getLayer()->getAggregator()` which is `Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Aggregation` is turned off:

```
45 class Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Aggregation extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
46 {        
47     const CACHE_FLAG_NAME   = 'layered_navigation';
48          
49     /**  
50      * Initialize resource model
51      */  
52     protected function _construct()
53     {    
54         $this->_init('catalogindex/aggregation');
55     }    
56          
57     protected function _isEnabled()
58     {    
59         return Mage::app()->useCache(self::CACHE_FLAG_NAME); 
           #returns FALSE as there is no layered_navigation cache type                                                                                                                  
60     }
```

What is more interesting is that if I try to set `return true;` in `_isEnabled` function Magento complains that no `catalogindex_aggregation` DB table is found.

Of course it is not found because Magento team turned it off by placing this file `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/sql/catalogindex_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php` that does nothing:

```
 $installer = $this;
 /* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

 $installer->startSetup();


 $installer->endSetup();
```

That means a fresh Magento 1.9.3.0 install doesn't have all catalogindex_* tables which means Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Aggregation won't cache attribute filter data.

Mage_CatalogIndex was supposed to cache layered_navigation data.

**Why was it turned off by Magento team**?

I also see that `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` is not cacheable. I wonder why Magento doesn't cache layered navigation at all. No wonder Magento has a reputation for being slow.

An insight from an expert would be appreciated.